# Tensorflow save final state of LSTM in dynamic_rnn for prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to save the final state of my LSTM such that it's included when I restore the model and can be used for prediction. As explained below, the Saver only has knowledge of the final state when I use `tf.assign`. However, this throws an error (also explained below).

During training I always feed the final LSTM state back into the network, as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112622/how-do-i-set-tensorflow-rnn-state-when-state-is-tuple-true). Here are the important parts of the code:

When building the graph:

```
            self.init_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [
                self.n_layers, 2, self.batch_size, self.n_hidden
            ])

            state_per_layer_list = tf.unstack(self.init_state, axis=0)

            rnn_tuple_state = tuple([
                tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple(state_per_layer_list[idx][0],
                                              state_per_layer_list[idx][1])

                for idx in range(self.n_layers)
            ])

            outputs, self.final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
                cell, inputs=self.inputs, initial_state=rnn_tuple_state)
```

And during training:

```
        _current_state = np.zeros((self.n_layers, 2, self.batch_size,
                                   self.n_hidden))

            _train_step, _current_state, _loss, _acc, summary = self.sess.run(
                [
                    self.train_step, self.final_state,
                    self.merged
                ],
                feed_dict={self.inputs: _inputs,
                           self.labels:_labels, 
                           self.init_state: _current_state})
```

When I later restore my model from a checkpoint, the final state is not restored as well. As outlined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112622/how-do-i-set-tensorflow-rnn-state-when-state-is-tuple-true) the problem is that the Saver has no knowledge of the new state. The post also suggests a solution, based on `tf.assign`. Regrettably, I cannot use the suggested

```
            assign_op = tf.assign(self.init_state, _current_state)
            self.sess.run(assign_op)
```

because self.init state is not a Variable but a placeholder. I get the error

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'

I have tried to solve this problem for several hours now but I can't get it to work.

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I have changed self.init_state to

```
            self.init_state = tf.get_variable('saved_state', shape=
            [self.n_layers, 2, self.batch_size, self.n_hidden])

            state_per_layer_list = tf.unstack(self.init_state, axis=0)

            rnn_tuple_state = tuple([
                tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple(state_per_layer_list[idx][0],
                                              state_per_layer_list[idx][1])

                for idx in range(self.n_layers)
            ])

            outputs, self.final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
                cell, inputs=self.inputs, initial_state=rnn_tuple_state)
```

And during training I don't feed a value for self.init_state:

```
            _train_step, _current_state, _loss, _acc, summary = self.sess.run(
                [
                    self.train_step, self.final_state,
                    self.merged
                ],
                feed_dict={self.inputs: _inputs,
                           self.labels:_labels})
```

However, I still can't run the assignment op. Know I get

TypeError: Expected float32 passed to parameter 'value' of op 'Assign', got (LSTMStateTuple(c=array([[ 0.07291573, -0.06366599, -0.23425588, ...,  0.05307654,

Comment: Your question _really_ looks like a duplicate of the one that you linked. The accepted answer indeed suggests you to turn the placeholder into a tf.Variable, so that you can update the state in the network with TensorFlow assignment operations.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. Maybe I am making a mistake when transforming it. How do I transform it to a tf.Variable correctly? Using self.init_state = tf.Variable(self.init_state) throws an error when initializing all variables

Comment: I changed the original question (see edit). It still doesn't work in the way it was explained in the other post. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

In order to save the final state, you can create a separate TF variable, then before saving the graph, run an `assign` op to assign your latest state to that variable, and then save the graph. The only thing you need to keep in mind is to declare that variable BEFORE you declare the `Saver`; otherwise it won't be included in the graph.

This is discussed at great detail here, including the working code:
[TF LSTM: Save State from training session for prediction session later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43663795/tf-lstm-save-state-from-training-session-for-prediction-session-later)

*** UPDATE: answers to followup questions:

It looks like you are using `BasicLSTMCell`, with `state_is_tuple=True`. The prior discussion that I referred you to used `GRUCell` with `state_is_tuple=False`. The details between the two are somewhat different, but the overall approach could be similar, so hopefully this should work for you:

During training, you first feed zeros as `initial_state` into `dynamic_rnn` and then keep re-feeding its own output back as input as `initial_state`. So, the LAST output state of our `dynamic_rnn` call is what you want to save for later. Since it results from a `sess.run()` call, essentially it's a numpy array (not a tensor and not a placeholder). So the question amounts to "how do I save a numpy array as a Tensorflow variable along with the rest of the variables in the graph." That's why you assign the final state to a variable whose only purpose is that.

So, code is something like this:

```
    # GRAPH DEFINITIONS:
    state_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [LAYERS, 2, None, CELL_SIZE], name='state_in')
    l = tf.unstack(state_in, axis=0)
    state_tup = tuple(
        [tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(l[idx][0], l[idx][1])
        for idx in range(NLAYERS)])
    #multicell = your BasicLSTMCell / MultiRNN definitions
    output, state_out = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multicell, X, dtype=tf.float32, initial_state=state_tup)

    savedState = tf.get_variable('savedState', shape=[LAYERS, 2, BATCHSIZE, CELL_SIZE])
    saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=1)

    in_state = np.zeros((LAYERS, 2, BATCHSIZE, CELL_SIZE))

    # TRAINING LOOP:
    feed_dict = {X: x, Y_: y_, batchsize: BATCHSIZE, state_in:in_state}
    _, out_state = sess.run([training_step, state_out], feed_dict=feed_dict)
    in_state = out_state

    # ONCE TRAINING IS OVER:
    assignOp = tf.assign(savedState, out_state)
    sess.run(assignOp)
    saver.save(sess, pathModel + '/my_model.ckpt')

    # RECOVERING IN A DIFFERENT PROGRAM:

    gInit = tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    lInit = tf.local_variables_initializer().run()
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(pathModel + 'my_model.ckpt.meta')
    new_saver.restore(sess, pathModel + 'my_model.ckpt')
    # retrieve State and get its LAST batch (latest obervarions)
    savedState = sess.run('savedState:0') # this is FULL state from training
    state = savedState[:,:,-1,:]  # -1 gets only the LAST batch of the state (latest seen observations)
    state = np.reshape(state, [state.shape[0], 2, -1, state.shape[2]]) #[LAYERS, 2, 1 (BATCH), SELL_SIZE]
    #x = .... (YOUR INPUTS)
    feed_dict = {'X:0': x, 'state_in:0':state}
    #PREDICTION LOOP:
    preds, state = sess.run(['preds:0', 'state_out:0'], feed_dict = feed_dict)
    # so now state will be re-fed into feed_dict with the next loop iteration
```

As mentioned, this is a modified approach of what works well for me with `GRUCell`, where `state_is_tuple = False`. I adapted it to try `BasicLSTMCell` with `state_is_tuple=True`. It works, but not as accurately as the original approach. I don't know yet whether its just because for me GRU is better than LSTM or for some other reason. See if this works for you...

Also keep in mind that, as you can see with the recovery and prediction code, your predictions will likely be based on a different batch size than your training loop (I guess batch of 1?) So you have to think through how to handle your recovered state -- just take the last batch? Or something else? This code takes the last layer of the saved state only (i.e. the most recent observations from training) because that's what was relevant for me...

Comment: Yes. I have seen that discussion and provided the link in my post. However, the provided code leaves out major parts, That's why it didn't help. If I understand you correctly, the "savedState" variable in your post is used solely for assigning the latest LSTM state to it in every epoch? But how do you feed in the lstm states during training? Are you using a placeholder as described above? In your post the "feed dict" is never fully specified.

Comment: Also, the code for restoring the variables in not clear. You run sess.run('savedState:0') to get the final lstm state in training. But how do you feed that information into the net? Which variable or placeholder is it given to?

Comment: Apols.. your question asked how to save the FINAL state for prediction, so I assume you were fine with how everything is done prior. I will update my answer in few secs..

Comment: Thanks, I will try to adapt the code for the contrib.rnn.LSTMCell I am using!